# How to track changes on a file?

Tags: google-drive-api

Is there a way to track changes on a Google Document / Spreadsheet?

When using

```
file.getModifiedDate()
```

the value does not properly reflect the latest changes on a document.
It sometimes takes many minutes until the file gets a new modification date when a user edits the content of the doc.

Is there a way to track *all* changes on a document no matter who did the changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the Changes feed to detect changes to files: https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-changes.

It doesn't allow filtering on a specific file, but each entry in the feed will have a `fileId` property to associate the change with a file.

Comment: But how do I get changes that have been made by other users? I mean if a document is shared and different users may be working on it, how do I get the last modification timestamp?
There may be some users that are working on the docs but I may not have the access tokens to request their changes feed...

Comment: The Changes feed will include changes made by all users. Obviously, you should have access to the document to see those changes.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that tomorrow :-)

Comment: It works somehow- but still it takes up to several minutes until changes show up. If I am performing a change after a long break it works, but it I do several changes in a short timeframe I do not get the subsequent changes. Is this normal behavior?

Comment: Some delay in propagating the changes is expected.

Comment: Ok, but I guess that it makes no difference then if I use the changes feed or just check the modification date?

Comment: The Changes feed is the recommended way to track changes to all files at once. If you only need to track one file whose id is known, then you should be fine polling its modification date.